# Can someone with a OnePlus 8T +5G (TMO) with working NFC tap-to-pay verify a setting for me?

Tags: settings

### **EDITED:**

I am attempting to troubleshoot my phone, which hasn't had Tap-to-Pay work since day 1, out of box brand new.  I suspect this is not a hardware problem (and have text results to somewhat affirm my hunch):

[image: screenshot2]

Long story short, I have some reason to believe there is a configuration issue.  I am using [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22) to sift through my settings databases, and one key value that struck me as being odd was the `available_terminal_list` key within `global table` (mine shows `HCEeSE1`).

[image: screenshot1]

I'm simply hoping to compare it against someone else's to either rule out or confirm I'm on the right track.  Thanks!

### EDIT 2:

To clarify, I'm aware that two ubiquitous forms of NFC communication form factors consist of *HCE* and *eSE* (host card emulation and embedded secure element); however, the value as shown doesn't appear to be correct, and I wasn't able to find anyone else's settings dump with an exact match for that key value pairing online.